# From view 1 to view 2

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I am stuck in my code. I can't make it to go to the other view when a user logins.

I have a class UILoginClass (Tableviewcontroller) And a class ImageViewController (viewcontroller).

Check image below.

I want to get from UILoginClass to ImageViewController but i can't make it. Anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a "push" segue from the view controller of the login screen to the image view controller (press ctrl and drag from source view controller icon to the destination view controller).

[image: ctrl+drag from source view controller to destination view controller]

2) Give that segue an identifier (click on the seque in IB --> attributes inspector --> identifier. It is just a string identifier that allows you to initiate that segue when you want to.

3) In code, when the login is validated, call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: with the identifier you gave to the segue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a push segue from Login Class to Image View Controller.  In the Xcode storyboard you add a segue by ctrl-clicking in the source and dragging to the destination.  Be sure to give the segue a name.  Then in the Login Class you can call the UIViewController method performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:.

Oh, and you can get rid of the push segue from your navigation controller to Image View Controller.